# AppleScript : find open tab in safari by name and open it

Tags: tabs, safari, applescript

I'm looking for a way to find if a webpage its open from all the opened tab, and if so, focus this tab.

I tried this code but obviously this is not working at all.

```
set closeURLs to {"http://www.yahoo.com"}

repeat with theURL in closeURLs
    tell application "Safari" to open (every tab of every window whose URL contains (contents of theURL))
end repeat
```

UPDATE : I find it : http://protips.maxmasnick.com/applescript-to-find-fastmail-tabs-in-safari

Comment: PS I also tried this  : tell application "Safari"
 set current tab to tab whose URL contains (contents of "https://www.yahoo.com")
end tell

Comment: I find i thttp://protips.maxmasnick.com/applescript-to-find-fastmail-tabs-in-safari

Comment: The method in that example is WAAAY cumbersome and not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an excellent script at [Find Safari Tabs with AppleScript](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/OSX/safari-tabs.html). If multiple tabs match the user input text, it shows a list of matching tabs and allows the user to select one to open.
It needed a couple of small mods to work with Mojave, so here is the updated code:

```applescript
set question to display dialog ("Find Safari tab whose name includes:") default answer ""
set searchpat to text returned of question

tell application "Safari"
    --
    -- *** Step 1. get a list of all tabs that match "searchpat" ***
    set winlist to every window
    set winmatchlist to {}
    set tabmatchlist to {}
    set tabnamematchlist to {}
    repeat with win in winlist
        if (count of tabs of win) is not equal to 0 then # ignore spurious windows with no tabs
            set tablist to every tab of win
            repeat with t in tablist
                if (searchpat is in (name of t as string)) or (searchpat is in (URL of t as string)) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & (index of t as string) & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                end if
            end repeat
            
        end if
    end repeat
    --
    -- *** Step 2. open the desired matching tab ***
    if (count of tabmatchlist) = 1 then
        set whichtab to (item 1 of tabnamematchlist)
        my openTab(whichtab)
    else if (count of tabmatchlist) = 0 then
        display notification "No matches"
    else
        set whichtab to choose from list of tabnamematchlist with prompt "The following tabs match, please select one:"
        if whichtab is not equal to false then
            my openTab(whichtab)
        end if
    end if
end tell

on openTab(whichtab)
    tell application "Safari"
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set tmp to text items of (whichtab as string)
        set w to (item 1 of tmp) as integer
        set t to (item 2 of tmp) as integer
        set current tab of window id w to tab t of window id w
        set index of window id w to 1
        -- this code is an essential work-around to activate a specific window ID in Mojave
        tell window id w
            set visible to false
            set visible to true
        end tell
    end tell
end openTab
```

Comment: is there a way to bring that tab in full focus in safari. After I perform this search it doesn't really allow me to interactive with it without clicking on page.

Comment: @David The above is still working for me exactly as-is in Catalina. The lines at the bottom to `set visible to false` and back to `true` are to address a bug in MacOS that doesn't activate the window when the index is set to 1 (bring to front). Try inserting a small delay in that section to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have a related question - a problem I ran into using this script - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432370/a-dialog-window-put-up-by-applescript-has-made-safari-unusable-why-how-can-i?noredirect=1#comment620005_432370

Answer (score 0):

Just try and find the tab whose URL contains the search pattern, and trap the error.

```
property checkURL : "yahoo"
try
    tell application "Safari" to set theTab to first tab of window 1 whose URL contains checkURL
    display dialog "That site is loaded"
on error
    display dialog "That site is not loaded"
end try
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script that is fast, and lets you use regular expressions for specifying either parts of the url, or the title of the tab. It also remembers the last searchterm, and also lets you list all tabs you got. :) You can find it here: [MacScripter / How to effectively converting a list of list into a single list](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=158082#p158082)

HTH

Comment: This looks like a great script, but it would be better to place a copy of it here along with the URL. Unfortunately there are text encoding problems on the linked site, so the script cannot be copied/pasted from there. For example, in the function `binarySearchinCumSum` I see `else if value â‰¤ item 1 of o's lst then` and `repeat until (value â‰¤ item`.